# GPS location on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, gps, coordinates

I have limited experience programming Android apps and none at all for iOS. Part of a future project of mine is to make my app be able to record the current location using GPS possibly on both Android and iOS.

Can the GPS coordinates be taken in "Universal Transverse Mercator" format like in Google Earth for both platforms? If not, is there some way to calculate the coordinates to this format?

EDIT: Any chance anyone would know what format the functions in their respective APIs return?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Simplified_formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will provide a location object (class `Location` for Android and `CLLocation` for iOS). Both API have getters for latitude and longitude, which are `floats`. Latitude and longitude are the GPS coordinates wrt to the WGS84 reference elipsoid.

If you need to transform these into some other coordinate system there should be lots of references in the web.